# Cannot Open Camera In kdenlive Via IEEE1394

Tags: camera, video-editor, kdenlive, firewire

I am having difficulty getting a system to cooperate with a video camera using kdenlive and an IEEE1394 connection.

From running lshw, we can see there is a card for such connections recognized:

```
       *-firewire:0
            description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
            product: VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller
            vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
            physical id: 6
            bus info: pci@0000:04:06.0
            version: 46
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=32 maxlatency=32
            resources: irq:20 memory:fe701000-fe7017ff ioport:c080(size=128)
       *-firewire:1
            description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
            product: VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller
            vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
            physical id: e
            bus info: pci@0000:04:0e.0
            version: c0
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=32 maxlatency=32
            resources: irq:22 memory:fe700000-fe7007ff ioport:c000(size=128)
```

The installed system is Ubuntu 15.04.  The camera is a SONY HVR-HD1000U.

Screenshot from kdenlive when the camera is hooked up to the computer and working in playback mode:

[image: Screenshot showing kdenlive cannot see the camera]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kdenlive developers have a troubleshooting guide for this.

https://kdenlive.org/user-manual/troubleshooting-and-common-problems/troubleshooting-firewire-capture

In my experience this has usually been a permissions problem rather than a driver or kernel module one.  The guide does mention creating udev scripts but those are well documented.

Comment: Link is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

The above link to the troubleshooting guide is outdated. Use the following link instead:

https://old.kdenlive.org/user-manual/troubleshooting-and-common-problems/troubleshooting-firewire-capture

But it seems that the firewire/IEEE 1394 capture feature is no longer maintained:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=355967

Comment: Could you expand your answer to summarise the steps needed? It'll guard against "link rot" (if the link you've posted stops working).